# Assign value to variable dynamiclly in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I wonder if its possible to make a for loop or something similar when you need to assign a lot of values to variables?

```
store.item1 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item2 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item3 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item4 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item5 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item6 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item7 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item8 = @"asdasd"; 
store.item9 = @"asdasd";
```

something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    store.item%i = @"asds"; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Coding to do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    [store setValue:@"asdfasd" forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%d", i]];
}
```

But as the other answers advised ... this might not be what you really want if you're indeed working on a store.

Comment: you're welcome. But please really bear in mind that usually you don't do things like that. Use this only if you really know what you're doing. If you want to store some items, use arrays or whatever you want. Don't use a property for each item (what happens when one day you end up with, say, 10 items in the store?).

Comment: The store was just an example. I have a game that assign all the default values to all the players in the game. If I do this, my code will be about 10x shorter, and much easier :)

Answer (score 2):

As JiaYow said, use KVC.

This is a working exapmle:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Store : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item2;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item3;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item4;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item5;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *item6;
@end

@implementation Store
@synthesize item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6;
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Store *store = [[Store alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        [store setValue:@"asdfasd" forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%d", i]];
    }

    [p release];
}
```

Cheers,

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of variables, use `NSArray` to store them, not individual instance variables.